# Automating hline in longtable spanning many pages

Tags: longtable, automation

Typesetting a document with lots of multipage longtables, How is it possible to automate a `\hline` at end of page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={5cm,7cm},text={7cm,5cm},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|l|l|}
    \hline Name & B.Year & D.Year \\\hline\endhead
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `\endfoot` definition

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|l|l|}
\hline Name & B.Year & D.Year \\\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
    AAA & 2565 & 4879 \\
 [ ... ]
```