# Auto-bordered tables

Tags: tables, longtable

I am using package `longtable`. When I actually place a 'long table', at the page-end I've a row without any `hline` below it (which was also expected as there isn't any in the code). See this code -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{cc}
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

But if I try to put one `hline` manually I've two issues -

1. `hline` comes on the next page.
2. I've to adjust the `hline`s whenever I add some data.

If you see page 1 of the provided code, the table ends without one hline and on page 2 table starts without an `hline`. I want a package which will provide me **auto-bordered** tables over the pages. Which means even though no specific commands are issued, new page will auto generate the borders.

Comment: Put the lines in the \endhead/\endfoot command.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get this solution. Where exactly should I place this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184286/automating-hline-in-longtable-spanning-many-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your MWE. You have to remove the `\hline` from the first line of the code, and have headers and footer that only contain a `\hline` (if you do not want text that is repeated on every page). It is lot of information in the [longtable manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{cc}

\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot


        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        abcd&efgh\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```